# Returning an Object thats created within a method in another class | Removing the Content of a JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, return

In my Game, the Player is created using

```
handler.addPlayer(new Player(x, y, width, height, ID, handler));
```

and so far it works, but now I need to use this Player in another Classes Method.
Is there a way to detect this Player and return the Object through a Method ?

.

Also, when the Player dies, I want the JFrame in the main class to stop displaying the Game, and display the Menu Screen instead. I tried using

```
JPanel mp = new JPanel();
mp.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
[.. adding a button here ... ]
myFrame.removeAll();
myFrame.add(mp);
```

but the Game crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always have an instance of that `Object` in the class you want, so you just have to pass the actual object as a parameter to the new class' constructor, or set it through the setter. For example, if you need that player in a class called `A`:

```
public class A {
    // some attributes
    Player p = null;

    public A(Player p){
        this.p = p;
    }

    public void setPlayer(Player p) {
        this.p = p;
    }
}
```

So then from the class you define and initialize your player as `handler.addPlayer(...)`, you can create a new `A` object and pass the actual player as a parameter in the `A` constructor, or use the `setPlayer()`. This way, you'll be able to have an instance of the actual `Player` inside class `A`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If it was what you needed please accept the answer ;)

Comment: well it solves the first "problem" but the not the seconds one :P

Comment: Sorry, I missed the second part. What's the Menu Screen and the Game? Do you have each one of them in a different JFrames? If so, you can always use the `dispose()` method to release all of its resources, and the `setVisible(true/false)` one to hide and show what you need to. If you have the Menu and the Game in different JPanels, then you can pretty much use the `setVisible(true/false)` method too, to do the exact same thing I mentioned.

Comment: sounds somewhat easy ._. dont know why i didnt think of that xD thanks bro :D

Comment: Glad it helped! Keep coding!